# Building Perf with Babeltrace on CentOS 7.2 using rpms

Tags: centos7, perf, babeltrace

I wish to use CTF conversion with perf. From the scarce information around, I've figured out that I need to recompile perf.

I've installed the epel repository and used yum to install

```
babeltrace and libbabeltrace
```

for the run time as well as

```
libunwind-devel slang-devel libbabeltrace-devel and asciidoc
```

for compilation.

I cloned git.kernel.org (as alternative I also tried github.com/torvalds) and used

```
LIBBABELTRACE=1 make
```

to build the perf with babeltrace support. However, I get the error:

```
Makefile.config:780: No libbabeltrace found, disables 'perf data' CTF format support, please install libbabeltrace-dev[el]/libbabeltrace-ctf-dev
```

So I try adding `LIBBABELTRACE_DIR` with `/usr` but this, too, fails. Checking out the Makefile.conf, I see that the configuration is looking in the wrong places: it is set up to use a locally compiled babeltrace with well defined subdirectories (include and lib), but these are NOT used when installing from rpm (yum). The rpm places them in /usr/include/babeltrace and /usr/lib64.

Patching the Makefile also doesn't help.

So, short of being forced to use a locally compiled babeltrace, what options do I have?

This is for a cluster of 26 nodes and I really would prefer a simple 'yum install' as this simplifies restaging nodes when the get corrupted (we do research with them and regularily corrupt stuff) and does not require setting specific environments.

ADDENDUM:

I tried compiling babeltrace from `https://github.com/efficios/babeltrace.git`: this, too, fails with the error:

```
babeltrace-cfg-cli-args.c:2390:29: error: ‘POPT_ARG_LONGLONG’ undeclared (first use in this function)
```

and, surely enough, popt.h does not define `POPT_ARG_LONGLONG`.

Thanks in advance.